# How to make only one windows form show at a time?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms, combobox

i have a combobox that has 3 cases. case "0" opens a dialog saying, "Not a valid choice"
but case "1" and case"2" open up there own separate forms. (FormMain and Form3)

How do i make it so if Form3 is open FormMain Can not be opened, And a messagebox appear saying so. I do not just want the ".hide" function. I already have that set.

I have tried a few differant things, none of which worked. And i tried them in the formload and in the combobox selected index

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement some kind of a static class that will keep an instance of the currently shown form . 
make sure each form checks this static class before showing .

Something like this maybe .

```
    public static classs FormManager
{

    private static Form currentForm=null;
    public static Form CurrentForm
    {
        get
        {
            return currentForm;
        }
        set
        {
            this.currentForm=value;
            if (this.currentForm!=null)
                currentForm.Disposed+=(s,e)=>{FormManager.currentForm=null;};
        }
    }
}

//at each form

.
.
.
public void TryShowForm()
{
    if (FormManager.CurrentForm==null)
        FormManager.CurrentForm=this;
    this.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like modality is the correct solution for this problem.

You are currently using the [`Form.Show` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show.aspx) to show the selected child form. Replace that with the [`Form.ShowDialog` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swcta4hh.aspx), instead. The code looks the same, but the `ShowDialog` method shows the form as a modal dialog box, which means that the form must be closed before the user can interact with any other forms in your application.

Also, if case "0" is really "not a valid choice", you should strongly consider removing that option from the combobox entirely.

Comment: i had this already and that will be my next best solution. but my forms have a pause function so the user could navigate away and use other parts of the program as well. There is only one form i dont want them to be able to access if the other form is open and vise versa. With a messagebox saying so. I know the message box part but that the other part.

Comment: case "0" is so when the user hits the dropdown list they see

select one
option1
option2

So if they click on "Select One" i wanted a message showing them not valid and choose from the others. So may i ask, is this harmful or something? It works great and as needed. Then again im new to programming so i dont understand the harm in that. I appreciate your responses.

Comment: @james: Hmm, it's weird to have forms that can be "paused". I either can't imagine your design, or it's broken and going to be difficult for your users, too. You have to understand that typical users don't have the same mental model for an app that the developer has. And since you're struggling to figure out how to implement it, that should provide a hint that *other* Windows applications don't work that way, so your app will run counter to users' expectations, and that's never a good thing.

Comment: Anyway, have you considered just using `otherForm.Enabled = False` when you want to prevent the user from interacting with it? That is, use the `Form.Enabled` property as your "pause" button?

Comment: And "select one" shouldn't be an option in the combo box. You should indicate that with a `Label` control *next* to (or just above) the combo box.

Comment: Okay to explain better in formmain is game mode easy and in form3 is game mode medium. its a basic game and yes it does pause and resume. so that why i dont want game easy to open if game medium is already. but i will try your other method and see if that is what i am looking for.

Comment: And in any form i ever been on online when filling something out you always see a "select one" or "choose one" within the dropdown list. but yes it is also implemented as the text for the combo box.

Comment: Dim Paused As Boolean 
Private Sub FormMain_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = "P" Or e.KeyChar = "p" Then
            If Paused = True Then  'unpauses game
                Timer1.Enabled = True
                Paused = False
            Else
                Timer1.Enabled = False 'pauses game
                Paused = True
                MessageBox.Show("Game is paused. Press the ""P"" key on your keyboard to resume game.")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: That is the code i used to pause game but also have loadsetting where the game is set to pause = false. Anyways that is still not what im looking for. There must be a way no?

Comment: And in no way is my application hard for a user to understand or navigate. Which is another reason i like having message boxes indicate whenever something wont work for instance instead of just making one form not work when the other one is i want a message box saying it wont work so they know. Just like when my game is paused a message box shows game is paused and how to resume. so it is very user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the Form3 and FormMain dim statements public in a module.  When doing the test to see what is currently running, then you can check to see if the form is currently in use

```
Public newFrm3 as Form3
Public newFrmMain as FormMain

'blah blah blah
If IsNothing(Form3) then
    'form is closed, create new
    newFrm3 = new Form3
    newFrm3.Show
Else
    'form is currently running, display message etc to alert user.
End If
```

This assumes that when the user has closed a form, you set its corresponding variable to Nothing.

Comment: this is making me replace public with dim and doesent accept formmain for some reason but lets me debug with a warning and not error. But does not do what is intended. I put the coding in my main form load. (not formmain but form one). Is that correct?

Comment: ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
        Select Case ComboBox2.SelectedIndex

            Case 0
                Flashwindow(Me.Handle, 1)
                Dialog1.Show()

            Case 1
                Flashwindow(Me.Handle, 1)
                FormMain.Show()
                Dialog1.Hide()
                My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
                Form3.CanSelect = False
            Case Else

                If Form3.CanSelect = False Then
                    MessageBox.Show("NO")
                End If
        End Select

Comment: I tried that to and that didnt work but seems as if it should

Comment: @James,  the Public declarations should go in a module so it is visible by all forms.  The other code is an example of what should go in your Select statement for the comboBox (i.e. if option1 is selected, then do this...)  So what I have is a step towards your solution, not the whole thing.  I have used this before for very quick and dirty solutions.  It is not elegant, but it does work.